# it is possible that something works in R and not in Rstudio? The following code works in R and not in Rstudio

Tags: r

```
library(GJRM)
set.seed(0)
n <- 400
x1 <- round(runif(n))
x2 <- runif(n)
x3 <- runif(n)
f1 <- function(x) cos(pi*2*x) + sin(pi*x)
y1 <- -1.55 + 2*x1 + f1(x2) + rnorm(n)
dataSim <- data.frame(y1, x1, x2, x3)
resp.check(y1, "N")
eq.mu <- y1 ~ x1 + s(x2) + s(x3)
eq.s <- ~ s(x3)
fl <- list(eq.mu, eq.s)
out <- gamlss(fl, data = dataSim)
```

In Rstudio this is the output of "out"

> Error in signif(x$G.deviance) :     non-numeric argument to
> mathematical function

This is the example of page 21 of the document:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GJRM/GJRM.pdf

Why?

Comment: Hm. Works fine on my machine. R 4.0.2. RStudio 1.3.959. However, a colleague of mine lately reported some issues when running his code using an old version of RStudio.

Comment: The codes works fine here too R 4.0.2 Rstudio 1.3.1056.
Does your RStudio works on the same R version than the Rscript your using ? If not press CTRL when you start RStudio to chose the right version of R

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in both.  Others have commented similarly.  If you want to see what the differences are, run

```
sessionInfo()
```

in both R and RStudio and compare the results.  For example, when I run it I get the output below.  I've broken it up to point out what to look for:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
```

Check that the R versions match.

```
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
```

Are they both 64 bit?  Most of the things in the next section should be the same in both systems.

```
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Compare which packages are attached.  If one system has different packages here, they could be overriding the basic ones.  Also compare the versions of attached packages.  (Attached packages are the ones loaded using `library()`.)  Also compare the versions of the "loaded" packages below:  these ones are loaded indirectly by the packages above.

```
other attached packages:
[1] GJRM_0.2-2   mgcv_1.8-33  nlme_3.1-149

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ismev_1.42          tidyselect_1.1.0    purrr_0.3.4         mitools_2.4         splines_4.0.2       lattice_0.20-41    
 [7] pcaPP_1.9-73        colorspace_1.4-1    vctrs_0.3.3         generics_0.0.2      stats4_4.0.2        gmp_0.6-0          
[13] survival_3.2-3      rlang_0.4.7         pillar_1.4.6        Rmpfr_0.8-1         glue_1.4.2          DBI_1.1.0          
[19] distrEx_2.8.0       VineCopula_2.3.0    matrixStats_0.56.0  trust_0.1-8         lifecycle_0.2.0     munsell_0.5.0      
[25] gtable_0.3.0        pspline_1.0-18      mvtnorm_1.1-1       VGAM_1.1-3          psych_2.0.7         magic_1.5-9        
[31] gamlss.dist_5.1-7   ADGofTest_0.3       copula_1.0-0        trustOptim_0.8.6.2  parallel_4.0.2      evd_2.3-3          
[37] Rcpp_1.0.5          scales_1.1.1        startupmsg_0.9.6    scam_1.2-6          tmvnsim_1.0-2       abind_1.4-5        
[43] mnormt_2.0.1        ggplot2_3.3.2       dplyr_1.0.2         distr_2.8.0         gsl_2.1-6           survey_4.0         
[49] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 grid_4.0.2          stabledist_0.7-1    tools_4.0.2         magrittr_1.5        tibble_3.0.3       
[55] crayon_1.3.4        pkgconfig_2.0.3     ellipsis_0.3.1      MASS_7.3-52         Matrix_1.2-18       matrixcalc_1.0-3   
[61] R6_2.4.1            sfsmisc_1.1-7       compiler_4.0.2
```

If you notice that one system has older versions, run `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` to update everything.

Comment: Thank you very much for these steps. I followed them one by one, and there were 4 packages that were installed in RStudio and not in R. Within this list was the package "gamlss".  I think the "gamlss" package and the "GJRM" package have conflicts. For now my solution was to uninstall the gamlss package and leave only the "GJRM" package, both in R and in Rstudio. If anyone has had the same problem, please write it down. Thank you very much!

Comment: For future readers:  it is probably not necessary to uninstall `gamlss`, it should be enough just to avoid loading it.  That worked for me.  But since packages can load other packages conditionally, the uninstall that Laura did is more certain to avoid the conflict.